# Native hybrid app - Keyboard keeps empty space after resigning

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, phonegap-build, virtual-keyboard

I am creating the hybrid app with help of PhoneGap. On iOS 7 device; iPad Air in my case, is behaving differently.

When user click on text-field a virtual keyboard open up. When user click on cancel button he is redirected to different view where page height is reduced and you can see a empty space instead of keyboard.

Keyboard resign itself is the expected behavior but it should not leave the empty space behind. Please refer following figure  for the reference.

[image]

When user change the orientation the empty space is removed and now page show content normally.

Note - I am using "build.phonegap.com" to create a build.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using iOS7 on an iPad Air? Update?

The content is in a division of some kind - you need to refresh it somehow. What framework are you using? If jQuery Mobile you'll need to run enhancewithin()

Comment: Actually its a requirement thus I have no choice of updating the OS.

I am using AngularJS with HTML5 as a development framework.

Comment: If you're using angular why not use ionic?

Comment: Can't change that as well; requirement :(

Comment: But Ionic IS Angular. Have your tried using the apply() method?